# Removing emails from inbox via python and IMAP4

Tags: python, email, python-3.x

I'm kind of a beginner at all this coding stuff and as part of a project I'm trying to write a bit of python code that reads off the first unread email (oldest email first), prints the contents and then deletes the email from the inbox, here's the code I have, but I cant make it delete the email, I've been googling this for hours now and haven't got anywhere.

```
#readyourmail.py
import imaplib
import email
def readmail():
    try:
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
        mail.login('email','password')
        mail.select('inbox')
        result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL")
        latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[0]
        result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = email_data[0][1]
        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
        for part in email_message.walk():
            if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                print(body.decode('utf-8'))
            else:
                continue
        mail.store(latest_email_uid,'+FLAGS','\\Deleted')
        mail.expunge()
    except:
        print("No valid emails")
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using UID command to fetch mail, You have to use UID coomand to delete it.

Try the below code.

```
mail.uid('STORE', latest_email_uid , '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted)')  
mail.expunge()
```